# Dictionary, Lists and Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

A decoder based on a **Dictionary**, it gets input as a **List** and splits it into single **Strings** so the **Dictionary** can be called to translate.

I know there's a way to simplify the code and make it drastically smaller but I don't know how.

Probably I should use the **index** in **variable** along with **len()** to make it smaller but couldn't find a way around it.

Yes I'am new to programming.

Thanks in advance!

```
decoder = {
"96": "0",
"97": "1",
"98": "2",
"99": "3",
"100": "4",
"101": "5",
"102": "6",
"103": "7",
"104": "8",
"105": "9",
}
test = list(str(num) for num in 
input("Enter the list items 
separated by space: 
").strip().split()).
length = len(test)
if length == 1:
    a, = test
    print(decoder[a])
elif length == 2:
    a, b = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
elif length == 3:
    a, b, c = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
elif length == 4:
    a, b, c, d = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
elif length == 5:
    a, b, c, d, e = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
elif length == 6:
    a, b, c, d, e, f = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
    print(decoder[f])
elif length == 7:
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
    print(decoder[f])
    print(decoder[g])
elif length == 8:
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
    print(decoder[f])
    print(decoder[g])
    print(decoder[h])
elif length == 9:
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = 
    test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
    print(decoder[f])
    print(decoder[g])
    print(decoder[h])
    print(decoder[i])
elif length == 10:
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = 
    test
    print(decoder[a])
    print(decoder[b])
    print(decoder[c])
    print(decoder[d])
    print(decoder[e])
    print(decoder[f])
    print(decoder[g])
    print(decoder[h])
    print(decoder[i])
    print(decoder[j])
```

Comment: `for item in test: print(decoder[item])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  in , the same you did to create the list out of the inputted items, and use a for loop to iterate through those items:

```
decoder = {
"96": "0",
"97": "1",
"98": "2",
"99": "3",
"100": "4",
"101": "5",
"102": "6",
"103": "7",
"104": "8",
"105": "9",
}

test = [str(num) for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space: ").strip().split()]

for item in test:
    print(decoder[item])
```

Also, note how I defined `test` using list comprehension :)

Comment: I tried it and it worked even without the list comprehension, why is that?

Comment: [List comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) is just one particular way of telling python you want to create a list. It's not _necessary_ to use it, but it's shorter to write and some times easier to read --at least once you get used to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you with keys that aren't in the decoder, too.

```py
decoder = {
"96": "0",
"97": "1",
"98": "2",
"99": "3",
"100": "4",
"101": "5",
"102": "6",
"103": "7",
"104": "8",
"105": "9",
}
test = list(str(num) for num in input("Enter the list items separated by space: ").strip().split())
for num in test:
    try:
        print(decoder[num])
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Num {num} is not in the decoder")
```

Comment: Such a cool and important addition. Works like a charm. Thanks mate!